# Selectively "erase" lines from TikZ matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I want to draw grids of arbitrary size using TikZ. I'm using the `matrix` library and I want to selectively "erase" some lines of it. I post an example of a brute-force solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix(lol)[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth,nodes={draw},text width=2em, text height=2em]{
         &  &  &  & \\
         &  &  &  & \\
         &  &  &  & \\
         &  &  &  & \\
    };
    \path[line width = 2pt, draw=white] (lol-2-2.north west) -- (lol-2-2.south west);
    \path[line width = 2pt, draw=white] (lol-3-5.north east) -- (lol-3-5.north west);
    \path[line width = 2pt, draw=white] (lol-3-2.south east) -- (lol-3-2.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

My solution has two obvious drawbacks:

1. The white line covers line intersections.
2. The white line is visible when exporting to other formats, e.g., PNG via ImageMagick.

Although 2 is not really important for me, I want to solve 1 as the grid looks really ugly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can avoid the unwanted cell borders by just not drawing them. To this end, this answer defines a style `pborder`, which accepts any combination of the letters `t`, `b`, `l` and `r`, representing `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` respectively. So

```
\path (0,4) node[pborder=tbl,font=\sffamily] (tbl) {tbl}
        node[right=of tbl,pborder=br,font=\sffamily] (br) {br};
```

will produce

[image]

and

```
\matrix(lol)[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,draw,
inner sep=-\pgflinewidth/2,outer sep=0pt,
row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
nodes={draw,outer sep=0pt},text width=2em, text height=2em]{
     &  &  &  & \\
   |[pborder=tbl]|  & |[pborder=tbr]|  &  &  & |[pborder=ltr]| \\
     & |[pborder=ltr]| &  &  & |[pborder=lbr]|  \\
     & |[pborder=lbr]|  &  &  & \\
};
```

[image]

So there is absolutely no overpainting whatsoever.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,matrix}
\usepgfmodule{parser}
\pgfparserdef{matrixborder}{initial}{the letter l}% 
{\draw (path picture bounding box.north west)
-- (path picture bounding box.south west);}% 
\pgfparserdef{matrixborder}{initial}{the letter r}% 
{\draw (path picture bounding box.north east)
-- (path picture bounding box.south east);}% 
\pgfparserdef{matrixborder}{initial}{the letter t}% 
{\draw (path picture bounding box.north west)
-- (path picture bounding box.north east);}% 
\pgfparserdef{matrixborder}{initial}{the letter b}% 
{\draw (path picture bounding box.south west)
-- (path picture bounding box.south east);}% 
\pgfparserdef{matrixborder}{initial}{the character ;}% 
{\pgfparserswitch{final}}
\tikzset{pborder/.style={draw=none,path picture={%
\pgfparserparse{matrixborder}#1;%
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0,4) node[pborder=tbl,font=\sffamily] (tbl) {tbl}
        node[right=of tbl,pborder=br,font=\sffamily] (br) {br};
    \matrix(lol)[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,draw,
    inner sep=-\pgflinewidth/2,outer sep=0pt,
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={draw,outer sep=0pt},text width=2em, text height=2em]{
         &  &  &  & \\
       |[pborder=tbl]|  & |[pborder=tbr]|  &  &  & |[pborder=ltr]| \\
         & |[pborder=ltr]| &  &  & |[pborder=lbr]|  \\
         & |[pborder=lbr]|  &  &  & \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could say that if you want to drop one border there should be a simpler way than adding all the borders that are not to be dropped. This slight extension does this. Now e.g. `|[pborder=-r]|` drops the border on the right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,matrix}
\usepgfmodule{parser}
\newif\ifnegateborder
\negateborderfalse
\pgfparserdef{matrixborder}{initial}{the letter l}% 
{\ifnegateborder
\draw (path picture bounding box.north west)
-- (path picture bounding box.north east) 
|- (path picture bounding box.south west);
\else
\draw (path picture bounding box.north west)
-- (path picture bounding box.south west);
\fi}% 
\pgfparserdef{matrixborder}{initial}{the letter r}% 
{\ifnegateborder
\draw (path picture bounding box.north east)
-- (path picture bounding box.north west)
|- (path picture bounding box.south east);
\else
\draw (path picture bounding box.north east)
-- (path picture bounding box.south east);
\fi}% 
\pgfparserdef{matrixborder}{initial}{the letter t}% 
{\ifnegateborder
\draw (path picture bounding box.north west)
-- (path picture bounding box.south west)
-| (path picture bounding box.north east);
\else
\draw (path picture bounding box.north west)
-- (path picture bounding box.north east);
\fi}% 
\pgfparserdef{matrixborder}{initial}{the letter b}% 
{\ifnegateborder
\draw (path picture bounding box.south west)
-- (path picture bounding box.north west)
-| (path picture bounding box.south east);
\else
\draw (path picture bounding box.south west)
-- (path picture bounding box.south east);
\fi}% 
\pgfparserdef{matrixborder}{initial}{the character -}% 
{\negatebordertrue}%
\pgfparserdef{matrixborder}{initial}{the character ;}% 
{\pgfparserswitch{final}}%
\tikzset{pborder/.style={draw=none,path picture={%
\negateborderfalse
\pgfparserparse{matrixborder}#1;%
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix(lol)[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,draw,
    inner sep=-\pgflinewidth/2,outer sep=0pt,
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={draw,outer sep=0pt},text width=2em, text height=2em]{
         &  &  &  & \\
       |[pborder=-r]|  & |[pborder=-l]|  &  &  & |[pborder=-b]| \\
         & |[pborder=-b]| &  &  & |[pborder=-t]|  \\
         & |[pborder=-t]|  &  &  & \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much. ❤️

Comment: @JairoAraujo You're welcome! (I added a small extension that simplifies the syntax if you just want to drop one border.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Very cool parsing technique, thanks!

Comment: @frougon The pgfmanual has a lot of stuff which I continuously discover. (This one has already been used here and there, also by me. It is arguably more elegant than all these `\ifnextchar`s and `\expandafter`s.)

Answer (score 7):

Not sure exactly why you want to draw over the lines later, but one way you can work around the issue of the edges is to use `\shorten` to make the line slightly shorter

```
shorten <= 0.5\pgflinewidth, shorten >= 0.5\pgflinewidth
```

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,matrix}

\tikzset{Blank Out Line/.style={line width = 1pt, draw=white, shorten <= 0.5\pgflinewidth, shorten >= 0.5\pgflinewidth}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix(lol)[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth,nodes={draw},text width=2em, text height=2em]{
         &  &  &  & \\
         &  &  &  & \\
         &  &  &  & \\
         &  &  &  & \\
    };
    \path[Blank Out Line] (lol-2-2.north west) -- (lol-2-2.south west);
    \path[Blank Out Line] (lol-3-5.north east) -- (lol-3-5.north west);
    \path[Blank Out Line] (lol-3-2.south east) -- (lol-3-2.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses `shorten`, `\pgflinewidth` (as Peter Grill said above), and `line cap=rect`, without using `matrix` library.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
%\pagecolor{gray}     % uncomment for checking
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
%line width=3pt,      % uncomment for checking
line cap=rect]
\draw (0,0) grid (5,4);
\foreach \cutline in {
    (1,2)--+(90:1),
    (1,1)--+(0:1),
    (4,2)--+(0:1)
}
\draw[white,shorten >=\pgflinewidth,shorten <=\pgflinewidth] 
\cutline;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: No gray strips in pdf file, but there are some when converting to PNG using ImageMagick, even with `magick x.pdf -strip x.png` command.